# Как использовать переменную в качестве Name, для элемента WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

Мне интересно возможно ли использовать переменную, например типа String в качестве Name для Button.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что-то такое я хочу провернуть.
Кнопки в WPF называются q_1, q_2 ... q_20.

P.S. Все это для того чтобы менять видимость элемента, в зависимости от значения индекса массива.
Если первый элемент массива равен 0, то первая кнопка в WPF исчезает.

Comment: Name - не является зарезервированым словом - можно. Но "Name.r"  - то как вы написали - нельзя, потому что точка - зарезервирована для других целей.

Comment: Для доступа к элементу по его имени - нужно использовать или функцию похожую на Findчто-тоbyName или в крайнем случае рефлексию. Но для упрощения.... я бы порекомендовал просто создать массив кнопок, и присвоить в массив нужные кнопки (это довольно несложно получится) - т.к. боюсь что первые два способа для вас будут сложны. Не уверен что есть поиск по имени... думаю вам тут подскажут те кто часто с WPF сталкиваются.

Comment: На en so есть рабочий ответ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/636383/how-can-i-find-wpf-controls-by-name-or-type или используйте это, или делайте массив, но возможно рефлексия тоже прокатит.

Comment: Ерунду делаете! В WPF в первую очередь используются **XAML** и **Binding (привязки)**. Забудьте раз и на всегда про создание кнопок (UI элементов) в коде! Вместо этого подумайте, как это должно быть реализовано с точи зрения данных (классов). Вот ваша логика какая? Что вы хотите сделать? Я так предполагаю у вас есть некий список вопросов, ок, человек допустим ответил на первый, вы хотите чтоб он ушел в конце список (или скрылся) или что? Если да, то делайте у него свойство "статус" и на его основе сортируйте вывод. Вот продуймайте свою задачу так, будто у вас консольный проект, как поступите?

Comment: Вот я допустим [отвечал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1154540/220553), посмотрите __внимательно__ на то, как там все реализовано, вы видите хоть одно обращение к UI элементам? Видите хоть один `x:Name` (кроме стилей), через который я обращаюсь к контролу через код? Вот старайтесь изначально делать подобное, ибо в WPF другие подходы очень сильно вам ударят в будущем как по производительности, так и по всем остальным аспектам проекта. Попробуйте на основе этого примера сделать то, что вам надо, там всего пару изменений и код будет изменять видимость объекта (как вам вроде и надо).

Comment: У вас не должно быть 20 кнопок, у вас должен быть ItemsControl, привязанный к коллекции.

Comment: Вставьте пожалуйста код в вопрос текстом.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1759923/12888024, но все комментарии выше считаю валидными

Comment: ((Button)r). Visibility=visibility....