# C# WPF анимации

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Использую паттерн MVVM, и мне нужно проиграть анимацию тогда, когда в ViewModel выполняется какое либо условие, например когда я асинхронно посылаю запрос по HTTP протоколу, должна проиграть анимация в n секунд, и при этом меняться свойство opacity с X% до 0%. После того, как данные пришли, и я их десериализовал, мне нужно проиграть анимацию что выше, только в обратном порядке.

Comment: И в чем трудности? Если вы умеете работать по MVVM, то и анимация наверно не составит труда, верно? Делаете свойство, простое `bool`, у которого будет вызов INPC для оповещения интерфейса, ну а в XAML делаете триггер, где true = одна анимация, а false = другая. Все, получаете нужное вам. Как пример, могу дать вам [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1154540/220553), где плавно сменяется статус.

Comment: Спасибо, оказывается решение вполне простое, сейчас попробую реализовать!